# How to identify Context-Sensitive Grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Context-Sensitive Grammar is defined as a 4 tuple G = (V, Σ, R, S) where:

V is a finite set of elements known as variables.

Σ is a finite set of elements known as terminals

V ∩ Σ = Null (empty set)

S is an element of V and is known as the start variable.

R is a fine set of elements known as Production Rules. Each rule is like aAb -> ayb where A is in V, a and b is in (V union Σ) and y is in (V union Σ)+.

The following is an example of this type of grammar that I found a lot in the literature.

1. $s \to abc|aAbc$
2. $Ab \to bA$
3. $Ac \to Bbcc$
4. $bB \to Bb$
5. $aB \to aa | aaA$

my question is:
how this example could be of this type if there is no context for production 4 and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: the grammar in your example is strictly speaking not [context-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar). It is a [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar) (or non-contracting) grammar. In those grammars the main restriction is that the lefthand side of a production rule cannot be longer than the righthand side.

> A grammar is *monotonic* if its productions are of the form
> $\alpha \to \beta$ with $1\le |\alpha| \le |\beta|$.
> (Some sources require
> $\alpha$ to have at least one terminal symbol.)
>
> A grammar is *context-sensitive* if its productions are of the form
> $\alpha A \beta \to \alpha \gamma \beta$, with $A$ a nonterminal
> symbol and $|\gamma| \ge 1$. (This is basically a context-free
> production $A  \to \gamma$ which is only allowed in context
> $\alpha A \beta$. )

The two grammar types are equivalent. First, every context-sensitive grammar is also monotonic.
Conversely, it seems to be hard to construct a context-sensitive grammar from scratch, but there is [a simple algorithm to convert](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7735/4287) from monotonic to context-sensitive. Therefore most people are using the terminology alternately.

For an example of this conversion, see the detailed [answer by John L](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/150093/4287) which constructs a monotonous grammar for $\{x\#x^R\#x\mid x\in\{a,b\}^∗\}$ and from there a context-sensitive grammar for the same language using the standard technique.

Note the length restriction is essential. If we are allowed to shorthen the string, then we obtain the [type-0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar) (or unrestricted) grammar.